# bootstrap accordian doesn't work properly dynamically in laravel

Tags: php

I've a bootstrap accordian left navigation code as following (html,css,row) which is working fine. Which is basically Category & Sub Category. But when try to make it dynamic using php laravel it doesn't work correctly with the design. That means it break css.

## Templete code :

```
<div class="left-sidebar">
    <h2>Category</h2>
    <div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian"><!--category-productsr-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#sportswear">
                        <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                        Sportswear
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="sportswear" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Nike </a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Under Armour </a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Adidas </a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Puma</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">ASICS </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#">Kids</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#">Fashion</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#">Households</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/category-productsr-->

</div>
```

After googling & re-googling I reached near about my solution. But the problem now I'm facing is - I've a fa fa-plus icon class for that category which has subcategory. it's showing correctly for that category which has subcategory. But it showing as much time as it's subcategory present means- if one category has two subcategory then it showing two + icon & if some category has 3/4/5 subcategory & they are showing respective 3+/4+/5+ icon rather than showing one. How could I do that?

## Here is my code which make accordian dynamic:-

```
<div class="left-sidebar">
    <h2>Category</h2>
    <div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian"><!--category-productsr-->
        <?php
        $category = DB::table('tbl_category')
                ->where('publication_status', 1)
                ->get();

        $subcategory = DB::table('tbl_sub_category')
                ->where('publication_status', 1)
                ->get();
        ?>

        @foreach ($category as $v_cat)

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#{{$v_cat->category_id}}">
                        <?php echo $v_cat->category_name; ?>
                        @foreach($subcategory as $sub)
                        @if ($sub->category_id === $v_cat->category_id)
                        <span class="{{ $v_cat->category_id  === $sub->category_id ? "badge pull-right" : '' }}"><i class="{{ $v_cat->category_id  === $sub->category_id ? 'fa fa-plus' : '' }}"></i></span>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="{{$v_cat->category_id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="panel panel-title"><a href="{{URL::to('/flowers-category/'.$v_cat->category_name)}}">{{$v_cat->category_name}} Link </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <span class="info info-sign"><i>Subcategory</i></span>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($subcategory as $sub)
                        @if ($sub->category_id === $v_cat->category_id)
                        <li><a href="{{URL::to('/flowers-sub-category/'.$sub->sub_category_name)}}">{{$sub->sub_category_name}}</a></li>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div><!--/category-productsr-->
```

Note: Is there any process to check a div which class is used by that div. Is it possible to make a if statement with the class of a div. i.e, if(div.class == something) do something else do otherthings. if it's possible then I may able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop subcategory there. Just use:

```
   @if ($subcategory->where('category_id', $v_cat->category_id)->first())
       <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
   @endif
```

This line check whether the category has sub or not.

```
   @if ($subcategory->where('category_id', $v_cat->category_id)->first())
```

If you're new to laravel, I recommend checkout [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Comment: if I don't use loop subcategory there then it will feeding me following errors:-
**`ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: sub (View:C:\xampp\htdocs\cp\ap\fulerhut\resources\views\pages\home.blade.php)
Previous exceptions Undefined variable: sub (0)`**

For your kind information I didn't use model.That's why I've to loop over there.

**Is there any option to check a div having a specific class in php?**

Comment: Replace  `@foreach($subcategory as $sub)
                        @if ($sub->category_id === $v_cat->category_id)
                        <span class="{{ $v_cat->category_id  === $sub->category_id ? "badge pull-right" : '' }}"><i class="{{ $v_cat->category_id  === $sub->category_id ? 'fa fa-plus' : '' }}"></i></span>
                        @endif
                        @endforeach` with my 3 lines code

Comment: I did that. After replacing my code by yours it feeding me past commented errors. I didn't use Model.

Comment: If u replace your code with mine, it shouldn't have a variable `$sub` to begin with. how can u get the error?

Comment: u just need to replace in main category only. keep the same loop code in subcategory